# Remove query binding?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I get all published users:

```
User::where('published', 1)->get();
```

Now depending on a var I wish to remove the where clause binding in the above default query.

How can I remove a binding?

Comment: what do you mean by remove a binding?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing it, only apply it conditionally:

```php
$query = User::query();

if ($condition) {
    $query->where('published', 1);
}

return $query->get();
```

Comment: Its not an option to apply conditionally, need to remove it.

Comment: @panthro - are you sure? Removing an existing where clause involves a lot of hair pulling, and should be avoided at all costs. Can you show us why you can't apply it conditionally?

Comment: I need to apply published where clause to all queries, unless published is passed through as a parameter, $options = [['published', '=', 0],[someotheroption]...]

Comment: @panthro - passed where? What does "all queries" mean? We need way more information than that to be able to help you.

Comment: I already know what Im looking for, the question was simple, I just need a way to remove bindings, no need for me to go through how the app works.

Comment: all queries => global scope, parameter provided => disable that global scope - nice n easy as of L5.2. If you have older version, then use this https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/laravel-global-scope/blob/master/src/GlobalScope.php  If you really want to struggle with *removing* constraint that you manually applied, then look at the source linked and you'll get the idea. But if that's the case, then you'd definitely could use eloquent to serve you better.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another binding
`->orWhere('published', 0);`